# Dto extending RepresentationalModel always returns "link:[]" in tests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito, spring-hateoas

I was testing my Controllers with MockMvc but I needed Mockito's when method. When creating a new instance of UserDTO that extends RepresentationalModel from Spring Hateoas, it always returns :

```
{
    links: []
}
```

Even after stubbing using the when method from Mockito, it still returns an empty link. But when I access a specific attribute from the UserDTO, it returns just fine. For example when I do

assuming userDTO is an instance of UserDTO extending RepresentationalModel
`system.out.println(userDTO)` - this returns `links: []`

but when I do `system.out.println(userDTO.getUsername())` - this returns `**username of userDTO**`

How do I make it return

```
{
    id: "1",
    username: "username of userDTO",
    possibleLinks: ...
}
```

Comment: I'm using spring hateoas' (https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/1.0.x/api/org/springframework/hateoas/server/SimpleRepresentationModelAssembler.html) SimpleRepresentationModelAssembler to convert my userDTO to an entityModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own problem since its super trivial. I just needed a `toString` method in my DTO class